# filtrar as cidades por estado em Laravel com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, route

Tenho um campo de cidade e um de estado, gostaria de quando clicar no campo e selecionar um determinado estado, nas opções de cidade aparecer apenas as cidades relacionadas aquele estado em específico. ele esta no meu ambiente local - no Xampp e Mysql.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui lista os estados no cosole quando clico nele conforme a linha do scrupt, mas não conseguimos chamar a rota.

```
<script>
     $('#id_state').on('change', function(e){
         var id_selected_state = e.target.value;
         console.log(id_selected_state);

         $.get('/citiesByState/' + id_selected_state, function(data){ 
             
        });
 </script>
```

A rota estou desenvolvendo dessa forma, porém dá erro e não chama o controller para executar a função.

```
Route::get('citiesByState/{id_selected_state}', 'CitiesController@citiesByState')->name('citiesByState');
```

Esse Foi o controller que desenvolvi.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Helpers;
use App\Models\City;

class CitiesController extends Controller
{
    public function citiesByState($id_selected_state)
    {
     $cities = City::where('id_state', '=', $id_selected_state)->get();

     return $cities;

    }

}
```

Uso apena rotas WEB, não estou conseguindo chamar a rota a partir do javascript, para retornar apenas as cidades daquele estado selecionado.

O erro que dá é esse.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém puder me ajudar a com a resolução do erro da rota. Obrigado

Comment: o seu servidor está rodando em qual endereço: tipo (`localhost:8080`) ou `localhost` como demonstrado na imagem? não é isso? evite também colocar nome de rodas minúsculos com maiúsculo coloque o nome tudo em minúsculo

Comment: Esta no localhost

Comment: o erro é de não encontrado.

Comment: ele não esta encontrando. não estou conseguindo criar uma rota para obter os dados do java script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uma solução que eu vejo é fazer uma requisição POST com Ajax, algo assim:

```
 $.ajax({
      "url": "{{ route('citiesByState') }}",
      type: "POST",
      data: { id_selected_state: id_selected_state },
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      success: function (data) {
        //alterar lista de estados do select
      },
 });
```

E seria necessário alterar sua rota para receber requisições POST:

```
Route::post('citiesByState', 'CitiesController@citiesByState')->name('citiesByState');
```